# Have Chinese (and surrounding) cultures traditionally heated their milk?

Tags: china, food, asia

I’ve spoken with many middle aged Chinese people who have reported that for as long as they can remember, even growing up on a farm, they would never drink milk, even their own cattle’s, without first boiling it on the hob firstly. Yet many make claims that until later this century nobody ever pasteurized milk.

I’m mainly interested in Eastern Chinese cultures, but then realized that throughout history this might have been less well defined and even now is relatively broad. For that reason I wouldn’t mind comparative remarks on for example Mongolian, Korean, or Russian (or even Tibetan or Xinjiangese cultural traditions. Please feel free to scope your answer however it will seem most sensible and insight-yielding to do so.

Lastly please forgive my ignorance but I simply have no idea where I would start in trying to look for answers to this myself.

Comment: Boiling, or just heating? Pasteurization doesn't bring the milk to the boiling point.

Comment: Might it have something to do with lactose intolerance (which is common in Asian countries)? It appears that the [boiling breaks down the lactose](https://www.jyfs.org/does-cooking-milk-remove-lactose/) into something more digestible.

Comment: Can't have been for [terribly long](https://www.sixthtone.com/news/1005211) milk consumption prior to the contemporary period seems to have been pastry and yogurt. "In more remote parts of the country, foreign missionaries sometimes bought local draft animals like yellow cattle or water buffalo to milk, but the low quantities of nigh-undrinkable milk they produced were of little practical use. In bigger cities, like Shanghai, water buffalo milk was diluted, filtered, and steamed before consumption, though only desperate expatriates would touch it."

Comment: @T.E.D. My impression had been that it was a question of boiling, but I wouldn’t want that detail to ruin the question so broadened it.

Comment: @MCW interesting.

Comment: Boiling milk till it starts to rise used to be commonplace in the USSR - up until the collapse of the Communism and coming of civilization (western milk that doesn't spoil.) Nevertheless, raw milk, directly from the cow, known as "parnoe moloko", was considered as a delicacy when visiting villages.

Comment: @Seekinganswers It is just an ironic way to remind that the USSR seriously lagged behind the west in terms of quality and availability of the basic consumer goods.

Comment: @RogerVadim by “western milk that doesn’t spoil,” are you referring to pasteurised milk?

Comment: @Seekinganswers pasteurization is a rather old method - the milk that one bought in Soviet shops was also supposed to be pasteurized, but it wouldn't last more than a few days. I milk that remains good for more than a week certainly requires some more advance pasteurization technique. Unfortunately, it prevents from using it for making sone traditional dishes, based in spoilt milk.

Comment: @Seekinganswers from a brief glance in Wikipedia, there exist multiple techniques: thermization, pasteurization, sterilization, UHT and others, differing by temperature, rapidity of heating and cooling, method of heating, etc.

Comment: *Eastern Chinese cultures* Did you mean Chinese cultures and other cultures in the "East"?

Comment: @user103496 No, I mainly meant cultures of Eastern China as well as other cultures that surround them because I think that western Chinese cultures such as Tibetan probably have traditions of drinking lots of yak milk. But on second thought, I think it’s as good and interesting a question to ask with respect to western Chinese cultures as well so will edit it to broaden.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Chinese traditionally do not consume much milk and also do not like to consume raw meat (unlike some Europeans). The usual reason given is that raw meat would be unsafe to consume. So it looks more than plausible to me that Chinese would not drink raw milk for similar reasons.

Mongolians on the other hand consume lots of milk and also milk products. Not sure about 100 years ago, but nowadays there is a strong aversion against unprocessed meat or milk, also because it is considered unsanitary/unsafe. For most [milk products](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_cuisine#Typical_dishes) the first step is to boil the milk. [Airag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis) is produced from raw milk, but through fermentation and contains alcohol, so it is considered safe to consume.

Comment: One would imagine this has a lot to do with the prevalence of lactose intolerance among those different peoples. One reference I found indicated that 92% of Chinese adults are lactose intolerant.

Comment: @MCW possible, but then Chinese even boil their water, so there may be other factors as well.

Comment: @Jan: *Chinese even boil their water* Most people around the world (including the PRC) do not have access to clean drinking water from the tap and so have to boil it.

Comment: @user103496 I am aware of that, but in China the popularity of boiled water is often claimed to be greater than usual. See e.g. https://www.scmp.com/lifestyle/food-drink/article/3085202/why-do-chinese-people-love-drinking-hot-water